# Image fades in but covers up the text originally in the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div with a hidden image and another div inside of it. When the user has scrolled down to the midway point of the div, the image fades in. However, I want to keep the text in the other div visible. Here's a fiddle to clear any confusion: http://jsfiddle.net/8eudrmcx/16/

Notice how the text gets covered up as the image fades in. I understand that this is normal behavior, but I'm stumped as to how I can keep the text visible (and selectable).

HTML

```
<section>
    <img src="http://www.billboard.com/files/styles/promo_650/public/stylus/2029269-marilyn-manson-Agata-Alexander-617-409.jpg" class="overlay" />
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</section>
```

CSS

```
section {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}

.overlay {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

JS

```
function isScrolledIntoView($elem) {
   var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
   var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

   var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
   var elemMiddle = elemTop + $elem.height()/2;
   return docViewBottom >= elemMiddle && docViewTop <= elemMiddle;
}
$(window).scroll(function(){
   $elem = $("section"); //or what element you like
   if(isScrolledIntoView($elem)){
      $('.overlay').fadeIn();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to play with z-index of overlay and section http://jsfiddle.net/8eudrmcx/17/

```
   section {
        background-color: #000;
        color: #fff;
        height: 500px;
        width: 500px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .overlay {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        height: 500px;
        width: 500px;
        z-index: -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply `z-index`.

`z-index` defines the layer which an element must be placed in, and only non-statically positioned elements can have `z-index`, i.e relative, absolute.

This is how you do it:

```
 .overlay {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 1;
 }

 section p {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 2;
 }
```

Here's a good introduction to z-index at MDN:
[Understanding CSS z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index)